# Adding music player controls to notification in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

I created a notification with music player controls (shown below, Android 2.3.3) for my Android application. However, I'm facing an issue. In order to ensure standard behavior across all supported platforms (Android 2.2 - 4.2+) I set the notification background as black. I also couldn't use:

```
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent"
```

for text styles since they aren't available in Android 2.2. Is this an appropriate design approach or is there a better alternative?

[image]

Comment: Note that those controls will not be reliable until Android 4.1 and the big-style notifications. Notifications generally do not support buttons prior to that. It may work on a few devices, but far from all.

Comment: What do you mean by "not reliable". I've tested them on several devices and they work as expected.

Comment: By "not reliable", I mean just that. The buttons will not function as expected. See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/3R8nCeTHfZI